# Функция, копирующая значение любого типа. Си

Tags: c, указатели, malloc

```
void *copy(void *element, size_t element_size) {
    void *element_copy = malloc(element_size);
    *element_copy = *element; // incomplete type 'void' is not assignable
    return element_copy
}
```

Собственно, записать значение с помощью указателя, указывающего на `void`, я не могу. Что можно сделать? Как мне привести указатель `element_copy` к какому-то абстрактному *(?)* типу, с помощью которого я бы мог записать значение из `*element` в `*element_copy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `memcpy`.

Или приведите указатель `void*` в указатель типа `unsigned char *` и выполните побайтовое копирование.

Вроде

```
void *copy(void *element, size_t element_size) {
    void *element_copy = malloc(element_size);
    if (element_copy)
    {
        memcpy(element_copy, element, element_size);
    }
    return element_copy;
}
```

или

```
void *copy(void *element, size_t element_size) {
    void *element_copy = malloc(element_size);
    if (element_copy)
    {
        for(unsigned char * dest = (unsigned char *)element_copy,
            * src = (unsigned char *)element;
            dest < (unsigned char *)element_copy+element_size;
            *dest++ = *src++);
    }
    return element_copy;
}
```

(Не компилировал - так, показать идею).